# How to use same icon regular and solid type

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I try to use same icon regular and solid type in a react component. I can't load it with different name. Is there any way?

My icon loader:

```
import { faBell } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBell';
//import { faBell } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons/faBell';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

export const loadIcons = () => {
  library.add(
    faBell
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import { faBell } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBell';
import { faBell as anotherFaBell } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons/faBell';
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I can import it like that, but how can I use it in FontAwesomeIcon element?

Answer (score 4):

I can get result with below:

Not need to import anything for usage:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['far', 'bell']} />
```

We need load icons to library:

```
import { faBell } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBell';
import { faBell as farBell } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { library, IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

export const loadIcons = () => {
  library.add(faBell, farBell as IconDefinition);
};
```

**My first founding cannot pass type script rules but working:**

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faBell as faBellRegular } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons/faBell';

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBellRegular} />
```

But I can't find any solution for adding icon to library and using it strandard method.

Comment: That's a great finding. Especially the second code snippet! I was able to just use `faBell as farBell` and then adding it like `library.add(faBell, farBell)`!